# How do you view a PostScript .LOG file in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, postscript

PostScript often outputs a highly useful .log file with recordable info as well as its usual .pdf output.

.log files serve both as error messages and for intentional output.

This .log file is automatically generated by Adobe Acrobat Distiller or by GhostScript, while Google Drive apparently has a mechanism for viewing certain log files from certain programs.

What is the Google Drive .log viewing mechanism for a .ps input?

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is very bad for getting messages normally sent to STDOUT on a printer and maybe even hopeless. For example, I have posted a file on Google Drive to show the printer properties to be printed on paper by the printer. I modified the PostScript to send the same information to STDOUT using the "print" string before the "show" string. The output from the "print" string is lost by Google Drive. At least the page is displayed without complaints by Google and can be viewed or the code downloaded and examined here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F40q3RaQd1hhIVkcJwfFMU8FjYjIBaAU/view?usp=sharing

The communications sent to STDOUT could be captured and used to generate a PostScript page if that was desired. That seems like a lot of work just to get Google Drive to show some output. For example, I converted a program originally made to send the currentdeviceparams to STDOUT into a PostScript printed page format to be run on any printer or viewed in any distiller and downloadable below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wplIEiqKkjL965Cj3Ss3_ECT5tVUxhs5/view?usp=sharing

EDIT: Wow, I see you are already prepared with [print_divert_werr1.psl](https://www.tinaja.com/psutils/print_divert_werr1.psl) to generate the page views of program output.

An alternative would be to post the .log file from Acrobat on your website or anybody could download the PostScript from Google Drive and run the program to get their own output.

Comment: Apparently there is some way that Google Drive users with admin privileges can access log files from certain other software forms. A key question is how to gain admin and view these files and whether the PostScript .log files can quality.

Comment: zillions of PS programs whos main output is a log file can be viewed at https://www.tinaja.com/pssamp1.shtml

Comment: Thanks for the info. I see you can already translate the program output to a page view with your print_divert_werr1.psl file. I experimented with a few tests with good results. Very impressive.